# Rendering countdown timer

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a simple 3, 2, 1 countdown timer for my Vanilla Javascript maze game project. I am trying to incorporate MVC principles in an attempt to have a good coding structure but I am struggling to get my head around how I would configure this part of my app.

I have managed to get the number 3 to be rendered to the page but then the just stays there and is not replaced by the 2, 1 which is the expected behavior.

I have the countdown function in my **controller** (index.js):

```
let timer;

const countDown = () => {
    timer = 3;
    let startTimer = setInterval(() => {
        timer -= 1;
        if (timer < 0) {
            clearInterval(startTimer);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

My first question is, should this type of function be in the controller? I am struggling to get my head around MVC principles. I don't think it should go in a model file as it's not part of the app 'data' and I don't believe it should go in a view file as it technically doesn't actually deal with the rendering on the page.

The rendering of the timer is done in my **view** file (gameView.js):

```
export const renderCountdown = (timer) => {
    elements.timer.innerHTML = timer;
}
```

Both the countDown method and the renderCountdown methods are then called within the **controller** (index.js) within a 'startGame' method (this method is called when the user clicks on the start game button on the app):

```
const startGame = () => {
    countDown();
    renderCountdown(timer);

}
```

So my second question is how do I get the 2 and then the 1 to appear on the countdown timer?

Comment: Add `renderCountdown(timer);` after `timer -= 1;` inside `setInterval` code then it will show `2...1...0`.

Comment: Thank you this worked! Does the countDown method belong in the controller do you think?

Comment: I barely know structure of your app. But I would suggest it to be in `controller`.

Comment: Ok thank you. It is currently a very basic structure and just consists of the 2 files mentioned in my OP.